# Reading Lines Correctly Using Telnet

Tags: java, android, telnet

I have an Android app, which should receive and read NMEA-sentences

> e.g. $GPGLL,3751.65,S,14507.36,E*77

from a remote TCP-Server using Telnet protocol. I am using the `org.apache.commons.net.telnet.TelnetClient` library.

What works:

- Connecting to Server
- Reading some sentences without any error

Problem:
There are more than half of the sentences missing. I guess that it is a timing problem, perhaps this has also to do with the connection which gets restarted in every iteration.

Here is my `MainActivity.java`:

```
package com.example.clienttel;

import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import org.apache.commons.net.telnet.TelnetClient;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;

public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        // Go to ClientThread, where NMEA-sentences will be received
        int i;
        for (i = 0; i < 10000; i++)     // 10000 for testing
            new Thread(new ClientThread()).start();
    }

    class ClientThread implements Runnable {
        //@Override
        public void run() {
            TelnetClient telnet = new TelnetClient();

            // Variables
            String ADDRESS = "194.66.82.11";
            int PORT = 51000;
            String NMEA = null;
            final String TAG = "TestApp";

            // Connect To Server
            try {
                telnet.connect(ADDRESS, PORT);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            // Process NMEA-sentences
            InputStream inStream = telnet.getInputStream();
            BufferedReader r = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inStream));

            try {
                NMEA = r.readLine();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            // Ignore "...busy" sentences
            if (NMEA != null) {
                if(!(NMEA.equals("*** Serial port is busy ***"))) {
                    Log.i(TAG, NMEA);
                }
            }

            // Disconnect From Server
            try {
                telnet.disconnect();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Any help would be appreciated!

**EDIT:**

My code now looks like this:

```
package com.example.clienttel;

import android.os.Handler;
import android.os.Message;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;

import org.apache.commons.net.telnet.TelnetClient;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;

public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {
    // Variables
    public String ADDRESS = "194.66.82.11";
    public int PORT = 50100;
    public String NMEA = null;
    public final String TAG = "TestApp";
    public boolean first = true;


    // Handler in mainthread
    Handler handler = new Handler() {
        public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
            String dataString = "";
            Bundle bundle = msg.getData();

            Log.d("handleMessage", bundle.toString());
            if (bundle.containsKey("outgoingString")) {
                dataString = bundle.getString("outgoingString");
            }
        }
    };

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        ClientThread ct;
        ct = new ClientThread();
        ct.mhandler=handler;

        int i;
        for (i = 0; i < 10000; i++) {     // 10000 for testing
            // Go to ClientThread, where NMEA-sentences will be received
            //new Thread(new ClientThread()).start();
            ct.start();
        }
    }

    class ClientThread implements Runnable {
        public Handler mhandler = null;
        @Override
        public void run() {
            TelnetClient telnet = new TelnetClient();

            if (first) {
                // Connect To Server in 1st Iteration
                try {
                    telnet.connect(ADDRESS, PORT);
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                first = false;
            }

            // Process NMEA-sentences
            InputStream inStream = telnet.getInputStream();
            BufferedReader r = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inStream));

            try {
                NMEA = r.readLine();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            // Handler in ClientThread to send back
            Bundle b = new Bundle();

            b.putString("outgoingString", NMEA);

            Message m = mhandler.obtainMessage();
            m.setData(b);
            mhandler.sendMessage(m);
        }
    }
}
```

but I am not sure about the placement of the handlers

Comment: It is extremely inefficient to connect, read only one line, and disconnect. Why are you doing this? You should maintain the connection and keep reading lines from it until end of stream, if that ever occurs, or until your application needs to exit.

Comment: why is there a different thread for each line?

Comment: With `new Thread(new ClientThread()).start();` I am creating the thread, right? To call the thread multiple times, I tried `ClientThread.start();`, but it throws me an error in the IDE

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As @EJP said, opening an closing the connection for each line will kill the app...

A better approach is have the thread handle the communication(s) and wait for the next line, passing the data back to the main thread as a bundle message.

There are plenty of examples out there, but essentially you create a handler in your main thread:

```
Handler handler = new Handler()
{
    public void handleMessage(Message msg)
    {

        String dataString = "";

        Bundle bundle = msg.getData();

        Log.d("handleMessage", bundle.toString());
        if (bundle.containsKey("outgoingString"))
        {
            dataString = bundle.getString("outgoingString");

        }

        // you can handle other message types here....
   }
```

and pass it (the handler) to your ClientThread (here, as mhandler) where you can send the messages back:

```
Bundle b = new Bundle();

b.putString("outgoingString", outgoingText);
Message m = mhandler.obtainMessage();
m.setData(b);
mhandler.sendMessage(m);
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I introduced a new handler as you proposed; I also adjusted the connection to the server (it only connects in the 1st Iteration and then maintains). I just tested the code (EDIT, above), but the app suddenly crashed... I am not sure if the placement of both the handlers in mainthread and clientthread make sense. Any idea?

Comment: The handler needs to be outside of the onCreate() method (instantiated there is fine, but the reference should be part of the MainActivity class).  You also need to pass the handler  to the ClientThread instance -- something like:   ClientThread ct = new ClientThread(); ct.mhandler=handler; ct.start(); [as apposed to starting on the create, like you're doing now]

Comment: handler now is outside of the onCreate() method. But I'm still struggling a bit by passing the handler to the clientthread (see updated code above); after `ct.mhandler=handler;` the IDE suggests to create field "mhandler", and also after `ct.start();` it suggests to create a new "start" method   (sorry for such basic questions, I'm still a Java newbie)

Comment: You have the Handler mhandler = null; defined within the run() method.  Make it 'public Handler mhandler = null;' in the toplevel part of the ClientThread class, so that it can be accessed from the instantiator (main thread), as well as your inner class.

Comment: The Handler seems to be okay now, but the IDE still grumbles with .start() of `ct.start()`. I think .start() cannot be used here because
        `ClientThread ct;
        ct = new ClientThread();
        ct.mhandler=handler;`
is not really a thread, but a class (its just named as "ClientThread")?

Comment: Goto my profile, click on my website, open my resume, and call or email me.  We'll update this page with the outcome once we have it straightened out. Stuart